# jQuery click inside each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, click, each

I want to loop my click events, to make the code shorter. I might have 30 of these values later on.

**My working code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last_click = '';

    $("#title").click(function() { last_click = 'title'; });
    $("#subtitle").click(function() { last_click = 'subtitle'; });
    $("#test").click(function() { last_click = 'test'; });
});
```

**This is how I want it (not working)**

My guess is that the each-loop runs on dom ready and then never again and that way the click-event can never be triggered?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last_click = '';
    var contents = new Array();
    contents = ['title', 'subtitle', 'test'];

    $.each(contents , function(index, value){
        $("#" + value).click(function() { last_click = value; });
    });
});
```

If there is not solved like I would, I would be thankful for a nice workaround.

Comment: What you have should work.. What do you mean by triggering click event? You are binding the click event to list of elements in `contents`.

Comment: Just a side note: your `new Array()` in `contents` is clobbered in the next line by another array; it's not needed.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rS2Gb/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rather add a class to all elements you want to bind this to, eg `class="last-click"`
and define the binding once as:

```
$(".last-click").on('click', function() {
    last_click = this.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to make it shorter, give them all a similar class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var last_click = '';    
    $(".theclass").click(function() { 
        last_click = this.id; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have value attribute for your buttons or elements, you can do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var last_click = '';
    $("input").click(function() {
        last_click = $(this).attr('value');
        alert(last_click);
    });    
});​
```

I assumed that you are using "input type="button". Also here is the demo you can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/rS2Gb/5/